# Hide magento admin advanced menu and other menu items on left side in System Configuration

Tags: magento-1.9

I searched whole of google but could not find a hint to hide many of the admin menu items that are there on left side under System > Configuration. Please help with this. I want to hide few of the items like Advanced, System, Developer etc.

What I am able to achieve so far is disable top menu items by making them dependent on non-existing module, but this is not helping with the above mentioned menu items.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything to the code base to achieve this. Simply create a role for the users you need to restrict and assign their account said role. Read more here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles (I know link says CE1.8, but this applies to 1.9 as well)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, I am aware of this approach but I am looking at white labelling the admin part and handover whole over the admin to other party but without few menu items that I dont want them to mess with. Basically new admin will do only ecommerce part.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to restrict all admin account access to these areas from a maintainability standpoint. Please create an an admin account for them using roles. Simply don't supply them with the full admin credentials.